# a sql query from oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I am using `oracle 10g EE` database.I have one table mytable and has two columns and data is as follows:

**Note**: I want to find out data based on same value in 2nd column only, it does not matter whether there exists same or different value in first column.

`10` is repeated 3 times for `A, B and C` and `these 3 are required output`

similarly `20` is repeated 2 times for `C` and `D` and these are also required output

```
   column1             column2
--------------     ---------------

     A                  10 //required
     A                  10 //required        
     B                  10 //required
     C                  20//required
     D                  20//required
     E                  30--------not required as 30 is only here and not duplicated
     F                  40--------not required as 40 is only here and not duplicated
```

following output is required i.e. same value in 2nd column having same or different values in 1st column

```
   column1             column2
--------------     ---------------

     A                  10         
     A                  10           
     B                  10
     C                  20
     D                  20
```

Comment: So you want rows where `column2` has duplicate/triplicate/... values?

Comment: @arnep exactly i want what you said, rows having column2 has duplicate/triplicate/... values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column1,
       column2
  FROM <table> t1
 WHERE column2 IN (SELECT column2
                     FROM <table> t2
                    GROUP BY column2
                    HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: ya i have run your query but still to get response from oracle, i have waited

Comment: @saroj, how large is your table? What columns are indexed etc?

Comment: almost 2900 billion records are there, a huge database hence perhaps taking time

Comment: @saroj, unfortunately you'll always have a full table scan on your table as you are having to group the results and the optimiser cannot know if there are duplicate `column2` values until it has scanned all the rows. If you could limit the records scanned in some other way (another, preferably indexed, column on the table perhaps) then the query would run faster but with what you have given us so far it's the best that can be offered.

Comment: @saroj, if you can then that would be preferable. If your table has 2900 billion records then is it partitioned? Do you need to scan the whole table when you could perhaps just scan the most relevent partition? A FTS on 2900 billion records will take some time no matter what server is running it. :-)

Comment: It might be better in your case to think again about what you are trying to achieve and is there another way of doing it that is more efficient than just looking for duplicates in `column2`?

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicate rows from the table or just identify them for some other purpose?

Comment: no no i just want to find out duplicate rows only, is there any efficient way to get it, i am still to get the response from oracle

Comment: Unfortunately as the optimiser will need to scan every row of your table to identify all duplicates it is always going to require a full table scan (FTS) and on a table as large as yours that will take a very long time unless you can limit the rows scanned by using values in some other (indexed column).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name t1
 WHERE column2 IN( SELECT column2
                     FROM table_name t2
                    GROUP BY column2
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

This appears to work with your sample data

```
SQL> with table_name as (
  2    select 'A' column1, 10 column2 from dual union all
  3    select 'A', 10 from dual union all
  4    select 'B', 10 from dual union all
  5    select 'C', 20 from dual union all
  6    select 'D', 30 from dual)
  7  SELECT *
  8    FROM table_name t1
  9   WHERE column2 IN( SELECT column2
 10                       FROM table_name t2
 11                      GROUP BY column2
 12                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 );

C    COLUMN2
- ----------
B         10
A         10
A         10
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where column2 in ( select column2 from table group by coulmn2 having count(*)>1);

should work for you.

Thanks
Abhi